# create a three-dimensional plot of points

Tags: plot, ode, scilab

With which of the graphical functions of scilab could be obtained a graph as shown in the figures.

[plots:-pointplots3d from Maple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0RoE.jpg)

the x, y, z coordinates are the result of the ode function.
Thank you.

I try to reproduce this article in Scilab
[Solving Algebraic Equations by the Dragilev Method](https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=149514&view=html)

Comment: Hi, welcome to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please enhance your questions by adding more details: what are the size of x,y and z ? What is the call to ode ? Please provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please take time to write a well formulated question. We will not read your article to find out what you're doing. This is not the purpose of this website. Have a look at [how to ask a question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I try to graph, the results obtained according to this script:

Answer (score 0):

I try to graph, the results obtained according to this script:

```
//Draghilev's Method
clear;
function Sys=Q(x,z)
Sys(1)=(x(1)-2)^2+(x(2)+2)^2+z^2-9;
Sys(2)=x(1)^6+x(2)^6+z^6-12;
endfunction
z=0;
[j,v,info]=fsolve([2;-0.1],list(Q,z))
disp(j,v,info)

//
N=100;
smin=0.0;
smax=0.046;
h=0.001;
x01=3.9691163496*10^-12;
x02=0.353580783;
x03=-1.530442808;
ics=[x01; x02; x03];

disp(["x(3)^2+(x(2)-2)^2+(x(1)-2)^2-9";"x(3)^6+x(2)^6+x(1)^6-12"],"systema")

disp(["2*(x(1)-2),2*(x(2)-2),2*x(3)";"6*x(1)^5,6*x(2)^5,6*x(3)^5"],"jacobian(Vm,[x(1),x(2),x(3)])"); //

//D1=12*x(2)^5*x(3)-12*(x(2)-2)*x(3)^5;
//D2=12*(x(1)-2)*x(3)^5-12*x(1)^5*x(3);
//DD=12*x(1)^5*(x(2)-2)-12*(x(1)-2)*x(2)^5;
function dydt=odes(t,x)
//dydt=zeros(x);
dydt(1)=-12*x(2)^5*x(3)-12*(x(2)-2)*x(3)^5;
dydt(2)=12*(x(1)-2)*x(3)^5-12*x(1)^5*x(3);
dydt(3)=12*x(1)^5*(x(2)-2)-12*(x(1)-2)*x(2)^5;
endfunction
step=0.0000005;
t=[smin:step:smax];
t0=0
atol=h/100000;
LL= ode( ics,t0, t,atol,odes)
```

The results to be plotted are in the LL variable. And I would like to get the graph shown above

Answer (score 0):

```
clf;
drawlater()
param3d(x,y,z);
set(gce(),"mark_mode","on","mark_style",2,"mark_size_unit","point","mark_size",4,"line_mode","off")
drawnow()
```